# Is it possible to resume a LINUX hibernation putting the disk (with the swap file or partition) in another computer?

Tags: virtual-machine, swap, ram, hibernate

Can I put my work computer into hibernation (when the RAM is copied to disk and the computer is shutdown), wait it to switch off, take the hard drive, put it into another (similar, but not identical) computer, turn on such computer and resume the execution state of the previous computer?

Differently from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287765/how-will-hibernation-work-in-two-linux-installations-sharing-a-swap-partition), the linux distributions are exactly the same. The computers have the same architecture (e.g., amd64), but could be more similar in other aspects (e.g., amount of RAM, display) if strictly needed.

A similar, but not so useful, question would be: Is it possible, *in general*, to store the execution state from one computer and resume it from another? [here, alternate solutions could be adopted, like mimicking the RAM in some way, virtualbox, some kind of synchronized central remote RAM, or any other means...]

The goal is to transparently resume working (with lots of open programs, heavy processing, etc.) in another location without moving the computer.

Comment: You have to mentions the specs and the similarities and/or the differences. Note that even if they are identical, plugging your drive to, say, the wrong SATA connector, will make it unavailable. And *wrong* in this case might even depend on the other system's BIOS.

Comment: This should really be on Superuser as it's not a Linux/Unix question but to address it anyway, this wouldn't be viable in any way, shape, or form. If it were switched off, then it would effectively power down which would be the end of the hibernation and would then have to go through its boot process again. Even it it did somehow come back up, the IDs for all of the devices in the new computer would be different which would render it inoperable. The best way to achieve your goal would be to use something like AWS.