# Is it possible to dual boot two Linux distributions and share swap space?

Tags: dual-boot, swap

I am trying to dual boot two Linux distributions. My machine is running MintOs and I am trying to install kali Linux. I need to know whether I have to create a new swap area or can I use the old one.

Comment: beware hibernation though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one OS should be running at any given time so sharing the same swap partition between the two OS should be fine.

Comment: What about swap files

Answer (score 1):

A Swap partition is just used for storing temporary files and often for swapping primary memory contents when there is low primary memory and other program is being stacked up in memory. This allows the OS to temporarily store the currently inactive portions of some programs in Swap partition and load new ones. Since there would be only a single OS running at a time, and the Swap partition being just another hard disk partition with a "swap" flag, you can allocate the same space as Swap space for multiple OS.

Tldr; It is possible to share the swap space between two OS and you don't need to create separate swap space.

Have a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/are-there-any-side-effects-when-two-distros-share-a-swap-partition)