# Separate /home from root? (Linux Mint)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, partition, root, home

My computer recently got messed up because of timeshift filling up all my storage. I had to erase my partitions and reinstall Mint.
Some users said to separate /home from root next time. In other places I read it's better to just have root and swap which is the default.
Should I reinstall making a separate /home partition?

I should add that I'm not using timeshift anymore, so is there still a risk of my root folder getting filled up to the point of no use?

Comment: An even better way to do it is to set up logical volumes. You can create a separate one for both root and home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever since version 2.4 of the Linux kernel, there's no advantage to having a separate swap partition if you only have one OS, so most folks just create a swap file when installing Linux, and put that in /root. So, you really only need /root.

(If you have multiple Linux OS, then each would have its own swap file, but could [share one swap partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/are-there-any-side-effects-when-two-distros-share-a-swap-partition), so in that case, so long as you don't ever use hibernation and don't virtualize, there are advantages to a swap partition.)

However, there is significant advantage to having a separate partition for /home, in that it makes backup of data easier. Since what you create and what you download goes into /home, separating that from /root means if /root is corrupted, or you need to install/re-install the OS, your data is intact.

Comment: Thanks, I reinstalled the OS and went with separate partitions.

Comment: I’m too low rated to upvote yet but you’re right I should’ve checkmarked